# Android Studio: exchange values (int) from between classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

1. sorry for my poor English, I am German and trying my best.
2. I am new to programming in general, and I know this question is very simple.

I want to exchange variables (integer) from one class to an other in Android Studio. The program is running, but the integer `c` from the other class always stays `0`.
I do not see why its not calculating like it should be and give this value (in this case 6) back?

```
public class MainActivity extends Calculate {

public int d;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void buttonClicked(View v){
    Calculate cObjekt = new Calculate();
    cObjekt.calc(2, 3);
    d=c;

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(Integer.toString(d));
}
```

}

```
public class Calculate extends Activity {

public int c=0;

public int calc(int a, int b) {
    c = a*b;
    return c;
}
```

}

I hope some can help ... do I need to work with a interface or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your buttonClicked method try :
d = cObjekt.calc(2,3);

Comment: Do not see why my version did not work, but ok its fine now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing this

```
int c = cObjekt.calc(2, 3);
d=c;
```